# C# Nuget package output location advise

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm working on a project for education and have a hard time with organizing the project.
For the past three-days i have been trying to find a solution but haven't found any yet.
I am trying to make the build output as clean and organized as possible.

**The issue**
I have loaded two nuget packges with both their depedencies.
So when i build my project, all the DLL files are being created in the main/root directory of the configuration profile (Debug or release.)

````
**Issue Terminal/bin/Debug/net5.0:**
/Core.dll (Project reference)
/MySql.Data.dll
/Terminal.Gui.dll
/Dependency1.dll
/Dependency2.dll
/Dependency3.dll
/Dependency...dll```

**Goal Terminal/bin/Debug/net5.0:**
/bin/server/Core.dll (project reference)
/bin/packages/MySql.Data.dll
/bin/packages/Terminal.Gui.dll
/bin/packages/Dependency1.dll
/bin/packages/Dependency2.dll
/bin/packages/Dependency4.dll
/bin/packages/Dependency....dll
````

Comment: All references needed to execute the program need to be in the same directory. You can put them at different places at compilation time if you want to for some reason, but the program won't work.

Comment: @MartinCostello is there anyway the reduce the amount of DLL's?
Because right now i have 18 DLL's for just 3 references

Comment: They're put there because they're needed somewhere in your dependency tree for your application to work. Is there any reason you want to have less files in the application directory other than "it's tidier"?

Comment: @MartinCostello Hello, the reason is the size of the project.

Comment: Maybe you should look into assembly-trimming then: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trim-self-contained

Comment: Since you're using .NET 5, would a single file executable work as the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write these on the `csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="CopyToDesintation" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(RuntimeCopyLocalItems)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)bin\packages"></Copy>
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)Core.dll" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)bin\server"></Copy> 
</Target>
```

**Then**, rebuild your project to check it.

**Update**

Please overwrite the `_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal` system default target

**1)** create a file called `Directory.Build.targets` file on the project folder:

[image]

**2)** add these on that file:

```
<Project>

    <Target Name="_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(RuntimeCopyLocalItems)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)bin\packages"></Copy>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)bin\server"></Copy>
        
    </Target>

</Project>
```

**Although** `server` folder contains the package dlls, it does not matter your need and the dlls are not in the root folder. And this is the best function I have ever found.

Comment: Hello @Perry, thank you for your reply.
I tried out your code but that did not solve my problem.
The project reference (Core.ddl) got copied to the custom folder but the original was still in the root folder.I could not start the app if i deleted the original. And Nuget reference did not get copied at all.

Comment: The `core.dll` is your reference project dll or a dll from the referenced project?

Comment: Hello Perry, the core.dll is a second project within the same solution. Used as a reference.

Comment: I found a better workaround, please check my updated answer.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you very very very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could package it as a single executable in .NET 5.

In the .csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

or via the CLI:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file

Comment: Hello @Nullforce, great idea! I have thought of this aswell.
Unfortunately at the end that is not the solution i am looking for. Edit: Also my project doesn't run anymore as a single file project.