# how to add stop msbuild from building the project visual studio build option

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks

I want to stop msbuild default "build" target to stop building my code instead, i want to define my custom target which will build my application. how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the `csproj` file of your project.

And add these at the bottom of the file:

```
<Target Name="Build">

//write your custom build function

</Target>
```

It will overwrite the default build and use yours.

Comment: when i added this in csproj, not effect but when i added these line in my msbuild extension and i could see that default build is stopped.  I ma checking further.

Comment: Or you could create a file called Directory.Build.targets in your project folder and then add my function into the file.

Comment: create a file and use the same thought under [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224433/c-sharp-nuget-package-output-location-advise).

Comment: when i added above code in my csproj, it is not working.  I have MSBuild extension in my project. as i mentioned earlier if i add this in extension, it works but in my case i want this behavior for few project and default build for few projects.  Can you suggest what could be issue when i put in csproj file?

Comment: Hi Perry Qian-MSFT , when I placed (Directory.Build.targets) in my project with Build target, worked for C# project, how ever when put same file in c++ project, Custom build target is not getting executed. Can you help for c++ project as well?